# JavaScript: If statement not working inside Loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm writing the following code (a test as of now) using Google Scripts to pass data from one spreadsheet to another. The passing of the code is working just fine, however my second For loop – which I intend to use to detect duplicate values and avoid passing those rows over – is not working.
Checking the logs I see that even though the "i" and "j" values are correctly being passed inside the If block, the "if(sheetsIDHome[i] == sheetsIDTarget[j])" statement is never triggering, even when I confirm that both values are the same.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
function move(){

  var homeBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = homeBook.getSheets()[0];//Sheet where my Home data is stored
  var limit = sheet.getLastRow(); //number of rows with content in them

  var evento = sheet.getRange(2, 1, limit-1).getValues(); //Even titles array
  var descript = sheet.getRange(2,2,limit-1).getValues(); //Event Descriptions array
  var tags = sheet.getRange(2,3,limit-1).getValues(); //Tags array
  var sheetsIDHome = sheet.getRange(2,4,limit-1).getValues(); //ID's array


  var targetBook = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1t3qMTu2opYffLmFfTuIbV6BrwsDe9iLHZJ_ZT89kHr8"); // Traget Workbook 
  var target = targetBook.getSheets()[0]; //Sheet1, this is my Target sheet
  if (target.getLastRow() > 1){
    var sheetsIDTarget = target.getRange(2, 4,target.getLastRow()-1).getValues();}
  else{
    var sheetsIDTarget = target.getRange(2, 4, 1).getValues();}
  var targetRow = target.getLastRow()+1; //Target row to start pasting content


   for (var i = 0; i < evento.length; i++) { //Loops throught every value from my Home sheet in order to pass it to my Target Sheet

     var isKlar = 1; //This works as a switch, data passing will not activate if isKlar set to 0

     Logger.log("Switch is: "+isKlar);

     for(var j = 0; j < sheetsIDTarget.length; j++){ //While having a certain "i" value in place, will loop though all my values in my target array using the counter "j"

       if(sheetsIDHome[i] == sheetsIDTarget[j]){ //If the ID of my curent row from Home matches any of the values in my target sheet, my "isKlar" switch should turn off and the break loop will be exited.          
         Logger.log("If Activated");
         isKlar = 0;
         break;}
       else{Logger.log("ID's: "+sheetsIDHome[i] + " vs " + sheetsIDTarget[j]);}
     }

       if(isKlar === 1){     //data passing will not activate if isKlar set to 0
         //pass data to the Target sheet
         target.getRange(targetRow,1).setValue(evento[i]);
         target.getRange(targetRow,2).setValue(descript[i]);
         target.getRange(targetRow,3).setValue(tags[i]);
         target.getRange(targetRow,4).setValue(sheetsIDHome[i]);
         targetRow++; //select the next available row in ny Target sheet
       }     
     }
   }
```

Edit. -  Right now I'm testing both ID arrays with the same numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4). The log inside my else statement does show the correct values being read for both arrays... I thought it was a scope issue, but now I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: what are the logged values of `sheetsIDHome[i]` and `sheetsIDTarget[j]`

Comment: Right now I'm testing both ID arrays with the same numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4). The log inside my else statement does show the correct values being read for both arrays... I thought it was a scope issue, but now I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: whether the type of both these values are same... ie number or string

Comment: They are the same type of value. At the moment only numbers. I've tried doing the logic with both "===" and "==". I've also tried doing it with a Switch statement with the exact same results.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is a sheet range.getValues() returns an array of arrays, not an array of values.

values[0] is the first row, and values[0][0] is the first value in that first row. rework your code knowing this.

Comment: Thank you very much Zig, I would've never thought of that. PROBLEM SOLVED.